# Identity Operator can be uniformly approximated by orthonormal basis

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $e_1, e_2, ...$.  I know that for any $x \in H$, we have $$\|x\|^2 = \sum\limits_n \|\langle x, e_n \rangle\|^2$$ and in fact $x = \lim\limits_{N \to \infty} \sum\limits_{n=1}^N \langle x, e_n \rangle e_n$ in the norm topology in $H$.  I was wonderdering whether this approximation is in any sense uniform.  In particular, whether it is true that $$\|1_H - T_N\| \to 0$$ where $T_N = \sum\limits_{n=1}^N \langle -,e_n \rangle e_n$.  I don't expect this to be true, but it would make my life a lot easier right now if it was.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not uniform.  For all $N$, $\|(1_H-T_N)e_{N+1}\|=1$, showing that $1_H-T_N$ has norm at least $1$. It is exactly $1$, as $1_H-T_N$ is the orthogonal projection onto the closed span of $\{e_n\}_{n\geq N+1}$.

More generally, note that the set of compact operators is norm closed, so a noncompact operator cannot be uniformly approximated by compact operators.